Why does Laravel 11 Sanctum not check xsrf-cookie anymore?
i'm using laravel 11 with laravel sanctum, i've config the sanctum as document. But at the first time i run in postman it's return code 419 CSRF token mismatch. then i put some code into Pre-request of postman like this:
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    method: 'GET',
}, function(error, response, {cookies}) {
    if(!error) {
        pm.collectionVariables.set('xsrf-cookie', cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
    }
});

then it can call to login api route. But now although i've cleaned cookies and comment the pre-request code, each time i hit the Send button, i run login api route without response 419 CSRF token mismatch. I don't know why and when it will require xsrf-cookie in header of POST request?
Here is some of my config:

.env

SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.local:4433,localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=.mydomain.local:4433,localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000


config\sanctum.php

'guard' => ['api'],
'middleware' => [
        'authenticate_session' => Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        'validate_csrf_token' => Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken::class,
    ],


bootstrap\app.php

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();
        $middleware->appendToGroup('api',[
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
//            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ]);

    })


routes\api.php

Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('login', [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'login']);
});

I've tried to find some answer on internet and compare with my configuration but nothing different.

I've run into a similar problem this week. Laravel 11 and sanctum with an electron js app using axios. 419 every time. Check the inspector under Application cookies for the XSRF-TOKEN cookie. I can see the cookie there. Made sure HttpOnly was off.  It's like axios just isn't seeing the cookie. I've tried multiple axios versions from current back to 1.5.0 and nada. Please let me know if you find a solution and I'll do the same for you.

Update: my problem was mostly due to my laravel app, and electron app being on different domains. laravel was on folder.test and electron app was localhost:5173. once I put laravel on localhost:8000 and changed SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS both to localhost it started working. Idk if this helps your case but I thought i'd share in the off chance it does.
